# b2Circle shape not rotating on b2Polygon shape Box2d Cocos2dx

Tags: box2d, cocos2d-x

well i have a car whose wheels are not moving forward while rotating on a rectangular block.

wheels -> b2CircleShape
rectangular block -> b2PolygonShape

i have given both the densities and friction . still nothing !

Specifically i have a wheel-joint operating between car chassis and wheels.
i want the car to move forward by giving the wheel-joint motor a positive speed.

Code :

```
b2PolygonShape boxSahpe;
boxSahpe.SetAsBox(68/PTM_RATIO, 40/PTM_RATIO);

b2BodyDef bd;
bd.type = b2_dynamicBody;

bd.position.Set(8.85f, 10.0f);
bd.userData = this;
body = world->CreateBody(&bd);
body->CreateFixture(&boxSahpe, 1.0f);


b2BodyDef circleBD;
circleBD.type = b2_dynamicBody;

b2CircleShape circle;
circle.m_radius = 0.4f;

b2FixtureDef fd;
fd.shape = &circle;
fd.density = 1.0f;
fd.friction = 0.9f;

// left
circleBD.position.Set(7.70f, 9.0f);
m_wheel1 = world->CreateBody(&circleBD);
m_wheel1->CreateFixture(&fd);

// right
circleBD.position.Set(9.75f, 9.0f);
m_wheel2 = world->CreateBody(&circleBD);
m_wheel2->CreateFixture(&fd);

b2WheelJointDef jd;
b2Vec2 axis(0.0f, 1.10f);

jd.Initialize(body, m_wheel1, m_wheel1->GetWorldCenter(), axis);
jd.motorSpeed = 0.0f;
jd.maxMotorTorque = 20.0f;
jd.enableMotor = true;
jd.frequencyHz = m_hz;
jd.dampingRatio = m_zeta;
m_spring1 = (b2WheelJoint*)world->CreateJoint(&jd);

jd.Initialize( body,m_wheel2, m_wheel2->GetPosition(), axis);
jd.motorSpeed = 0.0f;
jd.maxMotorTorque = 10.0f;
jd.enableMotor = false;
jd.frequencyHz = m_hz;
jd.dampingRatio = m_zeta;
m_spring2 = (b2WheelJoint*)world->CreateJoint(&jd);
```

m_spring 1 & 2 -> b2WheelJoint
m_wheel 1 & 2 -> b2Body
body -> b2Body

Comment: Do you mean the wheel body does not rotate at all, or it just does not rotate by the joint control? Show the code where you set up the joint.

Comment: there u go sire...
and yes the circle shape rotates at its position only doesnt move forward ...its like oil is spilled on ground and the wheel cant move forward...i have given both the rect block and wheel friction...

Comment: Why is the motor speed zero? What is the value of PTM_RATIO? Did you try making the speed non-zero, and the max torque higher? I tried your code with PTM_RATIO = 64 and motorSpeed = 10 and it runs fine.

Comment: sorry i just made m_wheel1 motor speed = 10.0f...PTM_RATIO=32;
still i am unable to run my wheel on rect block...it just rotates there only...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *really* recommend you use the debug draw display, otherwise it's like guessing with your eyes closed. In this case I think you would have immediately seen the problem yourself - here is what your situation is like when I try it:

[image]

With low values of frequencyHz (eg. 2) for the wheel joints, they do not have enough stiffness to hold the main body off the ground. You can make the frequencyHz higher (about 4 seems enough to get it moving), but I'm guessing you probably want to make the main body smaller as well.

Comment: this actually was not the only solution but it is marked for bringing the best practises to fore.I did what u said.

it is marked as an answer because it made me realise what goofiness i was doing by giving circle friction of 0.9f and box 0.6f.The box should have a larger friction than the acting body to stay where it is.